# myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination' not found

Tags: offsets

I have excluded the first 5 posts from the first page on the main page
This is the only code that works for me in my functions.php:

```
function my_function_for_excluding_posts( $query ) {
if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $offset = 5;
    $paged = 0 == $query->get( 'paged' ) ? 1 : $query->get( 'paged' );
    $query->set( 'offset', $paged * $offset );
    function myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination($found_posts, $query) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return $found_posts -5;
}
return $found_posts;

}
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_function_for_excluding_posts' );

add_filter('found_posts', 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );
```

But the admin panel error shows an error. How can I fix it?

Admin panel all posts

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination' not found or
>   invalid function name in
>   D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 298

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but you're calling a function "myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination" with the add_filter option, but you're not actually making that function unless it's on the homepage as that function is created behind the if is_home statement.   This would explain why you get the error on your admin page.  Try pulling that function out, or not that part of the code as a function.

Comment: thankyou sir, But I do not understand much
What kind of code should I create
can you help me please

Comment: remove thiss code: add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_function_for_excluding_posts' );
but error: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination' not found or invalid function name in D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Comment: remove this code: add_filter('found_posts', 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );

extra last page on the paginations, and 404 error